# How do I run only one test using Meteor and TinyTest?

Tags: meteor, tinytest

I'm using the "test-packages" command to run my meteor package tests.

```
meteor test-packages --once --driver-package 'test-in-console' -p 4096 package:name
```

I'd like to be able to run only one test or a subset of tests given a pattern. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Client side: you can click the "reload" link next to any text.

Server side: only way I found is to comment out the tests you don't want to run.